# Overriding value in resource with SharedPreference

Tags: java, android, arrays, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to figure out if there is an easy way to achieve what I"m doing. Basically I have some predefined values about some cities in my Strings.xml. But user the option to change it which I"m storing internally as SharedPReferences (in essence overriding the resource values).

Firstly I assume that this is one of the correct ways to do this. I'd like to keep my implementation simple as I understand how to do this and let's just assume this is an acceptable approach (if not, please provide some suggestion on doing this - but this is not what I'm looking at).

My problem is that I use an Iterator, List etc. and hence I'm using somewhat convoluted code to sort this. The code is as follows:

```
      // Get our predefined cities from our resources file
    String [] predefinedCities = res.getStringArray(R.array.predefined_cities);
    ArrayList<String> predefinedCitiesMinusOverridden = new ArrayList<String >();

    // Add values from our custom cities onto the Adapter via SharedPreferences
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Iterator<String> userCities = readCitiesFromPref();

     // Start of sort operation - to show these in alphabetical order
    List<String> copyOfUserCities = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (userCities.hasNext()){

        copyOfUserCities.add(userCities.next());

    }

    /* Code start to override resource value, i.e. remove resource value if
       our SharedPreferences contain the city. This means user has over-ridden values
     */

    int preDefCounter = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<predefinedCities.length; i++){ // for each city in predefined city

        boolean duplicateFound = false;

        for(int j=0; j<copyOfUserCities.size(); j++) { // check if there is match in user defined value

            if(predefinedCities[i].toString().equals(copyOfUserCities.get(j).toString())){

                duplicateFound = true; // Set that the string is found
                break; // NO need to continue checking this further

            }

        }

        // Here we finally find out whether to retain our preDefined city or not
        if(!duplicateFound){

            predefinedCitiesMinusOverridden.add(preDefCounter, predefinedCities[i]); // Retain it as new String
            preDefCounter++; // increment counter for our String Array

        }
    }

 /* End Code to remove duplicate values
     */

    ArrayList<String> sortedCities = new ArrayList<String>();
    sortedCities.addAll(copyOfUserCities);
    sortedCities.addAll(predefinedCitiesMinusOverridden);
    Collections.sort(sortedCities);
    sortedCities.add(0, "No City Selected"); // First selection should be "No City Selected"

    //End sort operation

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            sortedCities);
```

Is there a simpler way to do this instead of using 2 arrays, 2 loops, a counter etc?

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: apologies the code does work. I was looking at the wrong class. But maybe is there a simpler way to do the duplicate removal? I'll update the question

Comment: Check HashSet http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use one [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) object instead of two `ArrayList` objects. You have similar operations but different behavior for the `Set` collection type.

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets
>   contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at
>   most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models
>   the mathematical set abstraction.